# Python deepcopy, dictionary value in object changes

Tags: python, reference, copy

I have a python code snippet here:

```
import copy

class Foo(object):
    bar = dict()

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def loop(self):
        backup = copy.deepcopy(self)
        backup.bar[1] = "1"
        for i in range(0, 10):
            print "BACKUP BAR IS: ", backup.bar
            self.bar[1] = "42"
            self.bar = backup.bar

a = Foo({1:"0"})
a.loop()
```

This prints out `BACKUP BAR IS: {1: '1'}` the first two times, but then it starts to print out `BACKUP BAR IS: {1: '42'}` the next eight times. Can anyone tell my how and why this is happening? Doesn't `deepcopy` completely create a new instance of `self`? How does the value of `backup` bar change when we only change the value of "self", which is "a", in this case?

Edit: some have noted that the line `self.bar = backup.bar` causes the two dicts to point to each other. But, if we do:

```
 a = {1:1}
 b = {1:2}
 c = {1:3}
 a = b
 a = c
```

If a and b indeed point to the same dictionary, then all three values of a, b, c should be equal to c. But instead, `a = c = {1:3}, b = {1:2}`. So changing the reference of the left hand side doesn't change the reference of the right hand side. Similarly, how would `backup.bar` be changed if we're only changing `self.bar`?

Comment: I hope you're aware that `bar = dict()` and `self.bar` are two different objects (static class member vs. instance member)

Comment: In your last example you assign `b` to `a` and then `c` to `a` so you end up with `a` pointing to `c` but `b` was unchanged, why would you expect it to point to `c` as well ?

Answer (score 4):

Setting `self.bar = backup.bar` does not mutate the dictionary that `self.bar` is pointing to, nor does it create a copy of `backup.bar` to assign to `self.bar`. Rather, it changes the pointer of `self.bar` to refer to the dictionary at `backup.bar`, so that they now refer to the same object. Take a look at this demonstration:

```
In [48]: a = Foo({1: "0"})

In [49]: backup = copy.deepcopy(a)

In [50]: a.bar = backup.bar

In [51]: id(backup.bar)
Out[51]: 140428501511816

In [52]: id(a.bar)  # Same object! Alternatively, `a.bar is backup.bar` -> True
Out[52]: 140428501511816

In [53]: backup.bar[1] = "42"

In [54]: a.bar
Out[54]: {1: '42'}
```

The discrepancy with iteration is explained by @alfasin.

With regard to your question edit, you never change the dictionary that `b` points to. You're simply changing where `a` is pointing to twice. `a = c` does not mean *change b = c*. It simply means *a was pointing to b, now it's pointing to c*.

**Edit** drawings because why not.

```
a ---> {1: 1}
b ---> {1: 2}
c ---> {1: 3}
```

After `a = b`:

```
a --------   # So long, {1: 1}
         |
         v
b ---> {1: 2}
c ---> {1: 3}
```

After `a = c`, *i.e., a points to what c points to*:

```
a ---------------
                |
                |
b ---> {1: 2}   |
c ---> {1: 3} <-|
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the following two lines:

```
self.bar[1] = "42"
self.bar = backup.bar
```

On the first iteration you indeed don't change `backup.bar` which is why on the beginning of the second iteration it prints agains `{1:'1'}`.

BUT, since you set `self.bar = backup.bar` then by changing `self.bar` you're actully changing `backup.bar` since now both are pointing to the same object. So from now on (second iteration - *after* the printing) all the prints will show `BACKUP BAR IS:  {1: '42'}` (and from the second iteration and on - the second assignment will be redundant since, again, both point to the same object).

Comment: Okay, that is what I figured, but if we just try this with plain dictionaries:

Let a, b, c be dictionaries, and set a = b and a = c. 
When I try this in the interpreter, I do not get b = c or a = b anymore.

Comment: @lu6cifer better post a code example because understanding "code" in comments is a bit problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem lies in this line

```
self.bar = backup.bar
```

You're setting self.bar to now point to backup.bar so when you modify self.bar you are also modifying backup.bar and vice-versa